# Multiple colors in unit heatmap cell

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm trying to make a heatmap of this type of outcomes:

```
set.seed(123)
x<-sample(c(rep(0, 1000), rep(1, 90), rep(2, 60), rep(3, 60), rep(4:7, 10)), 1000,
       replace=T)
x<-matrix(x, 200,5)
x<-x[!duplicated(x),]
head(x)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    6    0    0
[2,]    0    3    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    2    0    0
[4,]    2    0    0    0    0
[5,]    3    0    0    0    0
[6,]    0    2    0    1    4
```

where 1:7 represents the presence of three type of species:

```
1=type1
2=type2
3=type3
4=type1+type3
5=type1+type2
6=type2+type3
7=type1+type2+type3
```

I'd use three-color system to make a heatmap such like:

```
1=green
2=blue
3=red
4=green/red (like up diagonal is green and lower diagonal is red)
5=green/blue
6=blue/red
7=green/blue/red
```

My question is how to apply these combined colors into a heatmap cell?

```
heatmap(x, Colv=NA)
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure whether it will be that easy to produce the map the way you want, but what about defining the colors you want to use by hand? You could code the "mixed" categories by the mixture of the respective base colors (e.g. 4 = green / red => brown, 5 = green/blue => turquoise etc)?

Comment: I agree that using a unique color for each of the values would be easiest. Having more than one color in a cell means you're not making a true heatmap anymore so it's not surprising that its difficult to make heatmap functions produce that output. you might consider just writing your own primitive plotting function if it's that important to you.